# Good destinations to travel as a family with a 2 year old

Tags: children, recommendations

Me and my wife are after a relatively exotic destination (travelling from the UK) with our currently 18 month year old son. We want to have a bit of a splurge before he becomes two and we'll need to buy plane tickets for him as well!

We currently have Morocco as one possible destination but are looking for other ideas. We'd like to avoid anywhere with Denge/Zika possible infection as well which narrows the options down quite a bit.

Does anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: A sad VTC from me. Sorry :-\

Comment: Kieran, questions asking for personal opinions/suggestions are OT here, try on the Tree Thorn Forum or in our chat

Comment: Your kid wants a place that is not hot with sand and water to play in. The back yard at home is prefered over the most exotic destination.

Comment: Passau springs instantly to mind. Took all of mine there as infants.  Colourful, sweets and ice cream, outside riverfront cafes, he can test his echo in all the cathedrals, afternoon boat trips, old-world charm, medieval castles, massively children friendly...  https://youtu.be/y3HU1-M1QqQ